# How to tell a beanstalkc receiver to wait X seconds before reserving a task?

Tags: python, beanstalkd, beanstalkc

I have 2 `beanstalkc` receivers watching the same tube `"tubename"`.

I would like one `beanstalkc` receiver to have priority over the other. In order to achieve this, I would like to tell the lowest-priority `beanstalkc` receiver to wait for task being X seconds old before reserving them.

I found [`"reserve-with-timeout"`](https://github.com/earl/beanstalkc/blob/master/beanstalkc.py#L153), but I neither really understand it nor do I managed to make it work successfully for my use case.

```py
class MyBeanstalkReceiver():
    def __init__(self, host=beanstalkc.DEFAULT_HOST, port=beanstalkc.DEFAULT_PORT,
                 tube="default", timeout=1):
        self.tube = tube
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.timeout = timeout

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.run_once()

    def run_once(self):
        job = self._get_task()

        try:
            body = job.body
            data = json.loads(body)
            self.job(data)
        except Exception as e:
            job.delete()

    def job(self, data):
        print(data)

    def beanstalk(self):
        beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection(host=self.host, port=self.port)
        beanstalk.use(self.tube)
        beanstalk.watch(self.tube)
        return beanstalk

    def _get_task(self):
        return self.beanstalk().reserve(self.timeout)
```

And my 2 `beanstalkc` receivers:

```py
# receiver 1
w = MyBeanstalkReceiver(hosts=["localhost:14711"], tube="tubename", timeout=1)
w.run()
```

```py
# receiver 2
w = MyBeanstalkReceiver(hosts=["localhost:14711"], tube="tubename", timeout=10000)
w.run()
```

Between the 2 receivers, with a timeout of 1 and 10000, nothing changes when I send tasks over the tube: both end up managing the same quantity of tasks put inside the tube `"tubename"`.

Any idea on how to proceed to make "receiver 1" prioritary over "receiver 2"?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout in `reserve` is for how long the client will wait before returning without a job.

You may be looking for [put (with a delay)](https://github.com/earl/beanstalkc/blob/70c2ffc41cc84b0a1ae557e470e1db89b7b61023/beanstalkc.py#L140), where the job is not released until it has been in the queue for at least *n* seconds.

There is also a priority per job. If the receiver could have seen them both at the same time, it will return any jobs with a higher priority (ie: closer to 0) rather than with a lower priority (with a larger number).

Answer (score 0):

Beanstalkd does not differentiate between priorities of the clients or receivers.